# An issue in designing a Card Trick Game using C#

Tags: c#

I want to create a card trick game using C#. I've designed Picture Boxes on the form to be the cards (backside). I also created a Click method for each of the pictures that creates a random number between 0, 51 and use the number to set an image from an ImageList.

```
        Random random = new Random();
        int i = random.Next(0, 51);
        pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[i];
```

My problem is that sometimes I get the same numbers (example: two Jacks of Spades), how can I prevent that?! (I mean if, for example, I got (5), I may get another (5))

Comment: It's still random! Do you want to make it so that you can only display a card once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Store the numbers you have already selected in a `HashSet<int>` and continue selecting until the current nunber is not in the `HashSet`:

```
// private HashSet<int> seen = new HashSet<int>();
// private Random random = new Random(); 

if (seen.Count == imageList1.Images.Count)
{
    // no cards left...
}

int card = random.Next(0, imageList1.Images.Count);
while (!seen.Add(card))
{
    card = random.Next(0, imageList1.Images.Count);
}

pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[card];
```

Or, If you need to select many numbers, you can fill an array with the sequential numbers and swap the number in each index with the number from another random index. Then take the top N needed items from the randomized array.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to make sure you have no repeat images, you can have a list of remaining cards, and remove the shown card each time.

```
Random random = new Random();    
List<int> remainingCards = new List<int>();

public void SetUp()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
        remainingCards.Add(i);
}

public void SetRandomImage()
{
   int i = random.Next(0, remainingCards.Count);
   pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[remainingCards[i]];
   remainingCards.RemoveAt(i);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an array of 52 cards. Shuffle the array (e.g. using the [Fisher-Yates shuffle](http://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle) which is fast) and then iterate when you want a new card.

```
int[] cards = new int[52]; 

//fill the array with values from 0 to 51 
for(int i = 0; i < cards.Length; i++)
{
    cards[i] = i;
}

int currentCard = 0;

Shuffle(cards);

//your cards are now randomised. You can iterate over them incrementally, 
//no need for a random select
pictureBox1.Image = imageList1.Images[currentCard];
currentCard++;


public static void Shuffle<T>(T[] array)
{
    var random = _random;
    for (int i = array.Length; i > 1; i--)
    {
        // Pick random element to swap.
        int j = random.Next(i); // 0 <= j <= i-1
        // Swap.
        T tmp = array[j];
        array[j] = array[i - 1];
        array[i - 1] = tmp;
    }
}
```

Essentially what you're doing is shuffling the deck and just taking the top card each time, like you would in a real game. There's no need to constantly pick a random index each time.

Comment: Ah sorry, I misread that. I thought they were wondering why they were getting the same number in a row.

Answer (score 1):

I think you may use a simple trick I ever used. Swap images between 2 random index for 50 times. less or more will give you a more varies of random. This may be similar with @faester's answer.